# How to prioritize one thread over the other when needed?

Tags: c++, multithreading

The title might me a little off but I have a very specific problem that I cannot seem to solve. I'll try to explain it as well as I can.

Let's say I have 2 threads (T1 and T2) listening on 2 different ports for messages (M1 and M2).

Messages are being sent from the same source with very little time between them.

There are way more M2 messages than M1 but M1 messages are prioritary and impact the M2 messages processing.

There's an execution lock so the threads won't execute at the same time.

I have an issue on this case:

M1 - leaves source 
M2 - leaves source immediately after 
For one reason or another the M2 message arrives at the target processed before M1 and  wakes up its thread. However, the data in M1 impacts the processing in M2 therefore I'm gonna get a wrong result.

Performance is an issue here and the number of M1 is way smaller than M2 so I cannot just wait in the M2 thread to see is an M1 is arriving because most of the time I'd be wasting time.

Up until now the best I could come up with is force thread_yield on thread for M2 messages before acquiring the execution lock in order to give the other thread the better chance but I feel like I'm putting my faith in the hands of the thread scheduler and since this is supposed to be portable I'd rather avoid doing that.

What are my options here?

Thank you

Comment: Should we assume a priority queue and a thread pool are off the table ?

Comment: Why don't you continue reading M2 and store it in some pending buffer until you get a notification from the thread processing M1 ? The caveat is that you need to make sure the threads handling M1 and M2 run in seperate cores by pinning it or something. Promise-Future seems to be a good candidate for sending this kind of notification.

Comment: If the two threads can't execute at the same time why are there two threads?

Comment: Yup. I have very little wiggle room here. I can't redesign. However, if you can suggest a solution using a priority queue and thread pool please do so. I'd be very grateful.

Comment: There is no guarantee that different messages sent to different ports will arrive in sequence at all. How long do you want T2 to wait before it's sure that no M1 has arrived?

Comment: @PeteBecker legacy

Comment: @nvoigt I'd like to avoid waiting here, performance is an issue and if I make T2 wait it will be waiting in vain most of the time

Comment: @Arunmu How would I know when to start processing the buffer? I cannot tell when M1 will ever arrive, if ever.

Comment: I would suggest using the same socket and that would ensure the proper ordering of the messages.
You can try and use a websocket or implement a channel mechanism above the socket.
Since you mentioned that the amount of M1 messages is small the overhead of adding them to the amount of M2 messages should be small as well(depending on their size)

Comment: @cpp_ninja So, you are saying there is no guarantee that M1 message will arrive ? Well, then have a max timeout as well. All the collected messages before the timeout will have to be processed or dropped (implementation choice).

Comment: @cpp_ninja Also, it would be efficient if you could keep partially processed M2 messages and then later do the complete processing on receiving M1.

Comment: Do you have an easy way to roll back changes made by M2 if an M1 arrives that should have been processed earlier?

Comment: @nvoigt I do. So what you're suggesting is, let M2 process, check M1 at the end, if there's an M1 rollback, else commit? Could work.

Comment: Yes, if that's easy to implement, then this could be the way to go. You will need to identify the sequence in which M? messages were *sent* (they can arrive in a different sequence) and if an M1 arrives that should have been processed earlier, roll back to that ID and start processing from that point again. Obviously, if this happens often you would be better off with waiting. And you will have "wrong" results in the system for an unspecified time in between.

Comment: "the data in M1 impacts the processing in M2 therefore I'm gonna get a wrong result." - No way to correct this with local synchronization/priorization. You're aware that you can never even know *if* M1 will arrive. So if the correctness of processing of M2 depends on knowing *if* a corresponding M1 *will* arrive you need to take other measures, e.g. design the message protocol appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you define a maximum delay parameter, which defines what is the longest time that an M1 message can reasonably be delayed behind the corresponding M2 messages. To avoid wasting this time, M2 can continue processing its messages and placing them into an intermediate results queue (doing as much of the computation as it can without 'committing', however you define this). So here is some example pseudo-code:

```
void handleM2SocketEvent()
{
    auto data = readFromSocket();
    auto result = preliminaryProcessData();
    resultQueue_.push_back(result);

    auto currTime = getTime();
    while(resultQueue_.front().processTime() + param_maxDelay > currTime) {
        resultQueue.front().commit();
        resultQueue.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What data are you trying to protect by locking thread execution so only one can operate at a time? It sounds like a major design flaw.

If changing this aspect of the design is not an option, then I would suggest that the two threads waiting on M1 & M2 simply place those messages into a queue. Then have a third thread process the queue. Because you want M1 to be higher priority then you can add any of those messages to the top of the queue.

The third thread will then monitor an event object which is signalled anytime an M1 message arrives. When the event is triggered, the third thread stops processing M2 and starts processing M1 first.

Comment: It still does not solve my problem completely because I'd have a race condition on that queue now. If M2 is put on the queue and T3 (the processing thread) starts processing it before M1 is put on the queue (event though the M1 existed) I'm still where I am now.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added some extra steps to my answer